# How to create a script that allows the user to send a survey email to another person three times with 30 day intervals

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

**EDITED:** I made a Google Apps script in which via Google Sheet, I can enter the number of the row of the person that I want to send an email to. The details of this person is stored into another sheet called 'tempSheet' where it also stores other details of other people that I want to send an email to.
The way my script works is that it adds an option in the menu and a button in which, when clicked, it will prompt the user to enter the row number of the person I want to send an email to. This is the gist of 'initializeNotif' and 'storeToTemp' functions. After storing the details into another spreadsheet, it will run the 'notifDecider' function which should check the date in the spreadsheet and decides whether or not to shorten the trigger time to less than 30 days but this is still a work in progress. For now, it defaults to the 'notifTrigger' function.

Now, this trigger function fires up every 30 days (five minutes for testing). This trigger function accesses the 'extractFromTemp' which gets the email and their details which will be used to create the html file for the format of the email. If this function successfully runs, it will increment the triggerCount by 1 and set the status into the following codes: 30 (initial status), 60 (30th day notif is sent, 60th day is next), 90, then DONE (all emails has been sent). The trigger self-deletes after firing three times.

Now, here's my problem. When I trigger the function and I allow it to finish, the trigger works and it sends the email successfully three times before deleting itself. But if I run it once then run it again with another email address, this happen: The first trigger works but the second trigger copies the trigger id of the first trigger. I have singled out the

Here is the test sheet that I made:
Dummy Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fQ8lzGv_Ekud5V9v8zsiz9AGwxX7zktIqMHToUykbXQ/edit?usp=sharing

NOTE:

- When testing twice simultaneously, please make sure to delete the triggers in the Google Apps Script because they will run until it returns an error.
- After testing, please delete the contents of the 'tempSheet' sheet.

I store the trigger id via script properties in which I pair an email associated with the trigger id. For some reason, it doesn't work as intended. Here is the excerpt from the script that I think is the culprit (I'm sorry if it's filled with mistakes):

```
// Function to extract data from temporary sheet
function extractFromTemp() {
  try {
    Logger.log("\nAccessed ExtractFromTemp\n");
    var tempSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var tempSheet = tempSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('tempSheet');
    var whileCounter = 3;
    surveyLink = tempSheet.getRange('G1').getValues();
    var triggerId = getTriggerId();
    var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    while (true) {
      const triggerCountRow = 'F' + whileCounter;
      const valueRow = 'A' + whileCounter;
      const emailRow = 'C' + whileCounter;

      const cellValue = tempSheet.getRange(valueRow).getValue();
      var triggerCount = tempSheet.getRange(triggerCountRow).getValue();
      const storedTriggerId = scriptProperties.getProperty(tempSheet.getRange(emailRow).getValue());

      if (cellValue == "30" && storedTriggerId == triggerId){
        Logger.log("Will Send 30 Day Survey");
        tempSheet.getRange(valueRow).setValue("60");
      } else if (cellValue == "60" && storedTriggerId == triggerId){
        Logger.log("Will Send 60 Day Survey");
        tempSheet.getRange(valueRow).setValue("90");
      } else if (cellValue == "90" && storedTriggerId == triggerId){
        Logger.log("Will Send 90 Day Survey");
        tempSheet.getRange(valueRow).setValue("DONE");
      } else if (whileCounter == 500){
        whileCounterIsNeverEnding();
        return false;
      } else {
        whileCounter++;
        continue;
      }
      Utilities.sleep(5000);
      triggerCount++;
      getInfoFromTempSheet(tempSheet, whileCounter);
      tempSheet.getRange(triggerCountRow).setValue(triggerCount);
      sendNotif();
      return false;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("extractFromTemp has encountered an error: " + error)
  }
}
```

I think because of the fact that it's accessing the same google sheet that it's
Is the whole thing possible? I will try to put the tempSheet in the same spreadsheet but for now, is there anything I missed?

Comment: I wonder if this question is too broad. A large of piece of code for a very specific purpose doesn't tend to do so well on Stack Overflow, because it requires someone to do some debugging that they cannot do without access to a testing environment. Can you cut this down to a small expression of the same problem?

Comment: I don't use Google Script, and so that may be why I don't understand the problem. But the bit about triggers, and the differences between your working and buggy cases, may require more description. It feels a bit vague at the moment, and a reader who can help may still require more precision.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I will try my best to edit my post. The problem is that whenever there are two or more triggers firing up, the new ones don't send the email to their associated email address, instead the email goes to the email address associated with the first trigger that fires up. I believe my script is facing concurrency issues since they are accessing one spreadsheet. I hope this clears it up but if ever, it didn't, please tell me anything.

Comment: Please add that detail to the post, by editing it. Comments are often mod-removed here, so the information there can only be fleeting.